# Why do we need second std::forward specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

As far as I can understand from this explanation of how `std::forward` works http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html we can dispense with only one version of `std::forward`:

```
template<class S>
S&& forward(typename remove_reference<S>::type& a) noexcept
```

But actually, we have (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) second version:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t );
```

which differs from previous one only in how `t` is defined (with `&&`)

So, why do we need it? What will break if remove it?

Comment: rvalue refs can't bind to the first overload.

Comment: Those are overloads, not specializations.

Comment: rvalue refs can't bind to the first overload. Ok, but what is the point to send rvalues to forward? Forward's intention is to forward arguments. So if we have arguments, we have names, and according to rule "if it has name then it is lvalue" t - always lvalue, is not it?

Comment: @Void, no, its intention is to forward while *preserving the value category* (see my answer).

Comment: [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) has a use case that explains why you may want to forward rvalues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments to the `std::forward` overloads (using the `std::remove_reference`) removes any reference collapsing and argument deduction that would have otherwise taken place and forces the lvalue and rvalue references to bind to the correct overload. This is also done without adding or removing any possible `const` that were part of (or not part of) the original argument `T` (i.e. we don't use a `const T&` because it essentially adds a `const` to the rvalue that `T&&` does not, yet they can both bind to the same rvalue).

A ***key error check is done*** in the rvalue reference overload; it is a sanity check to ensure that `std::forward` is not called to forward to an lvalue reference when an rvalue is provided; basically make sure that code like `std::forward<int&>(42);` fails to compile. `std::forward` is intended to be used in the formulaic `std::forward<T>` where `T` is from the deduced context `T&&` as noted in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward). The overload effects the same results as the conditional return with the required error checking.

The implementation(s) of `std::forward` is geared towards the "conditional cast" that Scott Meyers talks about in his [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler) talk. Scott Meyers gives the following pseudo code in his presentation to explain the workings of `std::forward` (at approximately the 20 minute mark);

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(T&& param) { // T&& here is formulated to disallow type deduction
  if (is_lvalue_reference<T>::value) {
    return param; // return type T&& collapses to T& in this case
  }
  else {
    return move(param); // return type is T&&
  }
}
```

`std::forward` is implemented to return an lvalue reference if the type of its argument is an lvalue, and an rvalue reference (equivalent to `std::move`) if the type of its argument type is an rvalue.

---

**TL;DR** *Why is it needed?* Basically; it protects against incorrect usage of `std::forward` (e.g. dangling references, references to temporaries no longer available, modify/modified literals etc.).

Comment: You are write: "so it is overloaded to effect the same results". But you are wrong. It seems that you do not understand rvalues. Here is example when you have only **ONE AND FIRST** version of forward (**with one &**), and all works perfectly (ie it handles rvalues properly, it returns rvalue!) - http://pastebin.com/PnaWefKF . And of course this is expected, since  u in example is lvalue (I cout its address to show it, finally it has a name)

Comment: As @Pradhan wrote above && - version is needed to handle rvalues, ie something like forward(move(u)), but my second question was - when do I need it? However I hope to find answer in this article http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html (see it also above)

Comment: @Void No, he's still right. `u` is techinally an lvalue in `make_unique` because it has a name (even though its type is `U&&`) . So when passing `u` to `Foward` it can sucessfully bind to the lvalue-reference. This is where the usefulness of the second overload for rvalue-references come in.

Comment: @Void. The implementation of `std::forward` is effectively only a `static_cast<T&&>` (and can be "made" to work as such), but the usage of the `static_cast` without the overloads forgoes any error checking and obscures the intent of `std::forward`, that is to maintain the lvalue/rvalue nature of the type of it's argument.

Comment: @Void, `Why is it needed?` basically it protects against incorrect usage of `std::forward` (e.g. dangling references, references to temporaries no longer available, modify/modified literals etc.).

Comment: @0x499602D2 So when passing u to Forward it can sucessfully bind to the lvalue-reference. Bind - yes, but forward returns it (lvalue ref) as rvalue (U&&). I showed it in code.

Comment: @Void Yes, it can return it as an rvalue-reference because it returning the result of a cast to an rvalue-reference.

Comment: @0x499602D2, no, when you see U&&, where U is template parameter U can be everyting - http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers (`void f(T&& param);               // here, “&&”does not mean rvalue reference`)

Comment: @Void Not in this context because the return type `S` in `Forward` is not being deduced so it's not a universal reference but only an rvalue-reference. The parameter `U&&` in `make_unique` is a universal reference and deduces the type to be `int`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, May be, but any way, I can write forward<int&>(something) and according to reference collapsing rules (http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) U&& becomes int & && which becomes int & => NOT RVALUE!

Comment: @Void Again. If `something` has a name, then it's an lvalue. That's why that code still works.